# How to prepare js files for production?

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, web-deployment

I'm planning to deploy my **Single Page Application** app soon and I'm not very much experienced with optimizations that can be done to make my app production-like.

I have all my **source** files (Js, CSS) combined and minified. I will use them for the production environment.

Currently, I'm using the minified version of all my dependencies **separately**. I've checked a lot of existing websites and they pretty much do the same. For example, [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org) website load their dependencies separately.

**AngularJS dependencies**

```
  <script src="google-code-prettify/prettify.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/homepage.js"></script>
  <script src="js/download-data.js"></script>
  <script src="js/angular-ui-bootstrap.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.0-beta.18/angular-route.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/1.0.18/firebase.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/angularfire/0.8.0/angularfire.min.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.18/i18n/angular-locale_sk.js"></script>
```

A co-worker gave us the idea about joining the source and dependencies together in two files, for example: **scripts.min.js** (this will include the JS code for the source and dependencies together) and **styles.min.css** (this will include the CSS code for the source and dependencies together).

**Question**: Is this a good idea? Are there any disadvantages?

I saw some existing posts about that but I was not able to get a consistent answer from them also.

Comment: I don't think it is an opinion-based question. You can look at the answers, all of them vote for unifying and this actually helped me solve my problem. Anyways, I will leave the judgment for you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe for the most part bundling your scripts and css into a single document is a good way to go.  You'll have the advantage of less requests to the server - and from what I've seen in fiddler your browser can only have so many requests going out at once.

Not sure how you would bundle CDN resources into a single file however.

The one disadvantage of bundling and minifying that I can think of would be it's much tougher to figure out where an issue occurs in your js when it happens on production, as all your whitespace and variable names are removed.

I'm sure there's a lot more pros and cons than this, but I think the final call is sort of opinion of what you want... faster load but tougher debug, easier debug but slightly slower load, etc.

Comment: http://visitmix.com/opinions/to-minify-or-not-to-minify

Comment: You may occasionally run into scripts that don't play well together if they're all concatenated into one. I surprisingly had some difficulties with bundling in the Google/Typekit webfontloader script with Angular library and app files (which were fine separately). And of course, if you're minifying your Angular scripts, make sure you're following syntax guidelines to ensure minified dependency injections don't end up unable to resolve. (see https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_05 ("Note on Minification")

Answer (score 2):

It's a good idea to reduce the number of HTTP requests made by your application.  Fewer files means fewer HTTP requests on page load.  In development, it's favorable to keep your app and vendor dependencies separate, since your app files are changing often, but the vendor files, probably not so much.  In production, concatenate and minify, and even uglify if you prefer.  Less is usually best.

Also, if you are developing in a Node.js environment, you might want to check out task runners like [Gulp](http://gulpjs.com/) or [Grunt](http://gruntjs.com/), which are great tools for processing assets in this manner.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on your situation. Off the top of my head...

**Advantages:**

- Less http requests
- Everything in one place
- Faster load times (I would suggest comparing to see if the difference is more than negligible)

**Disadvantages:**

- Harder to debug
- Loss of organization
- No separation between dependencies and YOUR source code

Personally, I would go for a `dependencies.min.js` & `.css`, `source.min.js` & `.css` approach. You will never be changing the code of the dependencies, so I don't think there would be a major disadvantage to keeping it all in one place. Your own source code, however, will be changing constantly and I think for the sake of organization I would just keep it separated. If you don't think that will be much of an issue, go ahead and combine them all into one document.

I would run a few tests- see if the condensed version is a significant improvement in load time. With smaller applications like yours, sometimes optimizations don't end up being worth it like they would in larger-scale projects.